# Finding a rational function from given extremas

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives

A function is given by 
$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(ax^2+2bx+c\right)}{Ax^2+2Bx+C}$$
It has points of extrema at **x=1** and **x=-1** such that **f(1)=2, f(-1)=3 and f(0)=2.5**. *Then find the value of a/A, prove that A=C and find the function f(x).*

My attempt:
I didn't want to  solve 4-6 linear equations, so I analyzed it graphically. As x tends to infinity, a/A must be in between 2 and 3. The graph was looking pretty symmetric and thus I **assumed** a/A=2.5 which is the solution given in my book. And then I got stuck. Any clever idea to tackle this question? Or I have to solve hell amount of equations to get to my answer?

Comment: My first step would be to rename $c$ and $C$ as $5k$ and $2k$, respectively. Then the values at $\pm1$ give you two linear equations in five variables. I’d see what those imply, and then look at the derivative...

Comment: That'd just mean solving everything algebraically.. that's too cumbersome. Yes, we can get two more equations by putting 1 and -1 in the derivative and equate it to zero.. that'd still not be enough (5 variables 4 equations)

Comment: Those last two equations would be nonlinear. That’s why I saved them for last.

Comment: I still don't get how would I proceed to solve this problem

Comment: Yeah..... I note that $(5,2,5,2,0,2)$ is a solution for $(a,b,c,A,B,C)$, and I didn't find it algebraically. I just tried to make that shape by dividing two quadratics to see if it was possible, and stumbled across something that worked.

Comment: This actually points to a clever solution, which isn't how I did it, but I see it now. I'll write out an answer later today.

Comment: By the way, there are really only $5$ unknowns. We can normalize any such function so that $a=1$ without loss of generality.

Comment: That solution above should be $(5,1,5,2,0,2)$. I keep forgetting about the built-in $2$ in front of $b$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good way to discover one solution. Showing that it's the only solution is a different matter.

We know that $f(x)$ has a max at $(1,3)$ and a min at $(-1,2)$. This means that $g(x)=f(x)-\frac52$ has a max at $(1,\frac12)$ and a min at $(-1,-\frac12)$. Let us make the assumption that $g$ is an odd function. In fact, we assume that $g$ is of the form: $$g(x)=\frac{\beta x}{Ax^2 + C}.$$ Since $g$ has the horizontal asymptote $y=0$, we can deduce the end behavior of $f$, so $\dfrac{a}{A}=\dfrac52$. As noted in a comment, we have one degree of freedom, so we take $a=5,A=2$

Now, $g$ (hence also $f$) has derivative: $$f'(x)=g'(x)=\frac{-\beta(Ax^2-C)}{(Ax^2+C)^2}.$$ If $x=\pm1$ are to be critical points, then $A=C$, as required.

Next, we want $g(1)=\dfrac12$, which will guarantee the correct value at $-1$ as well. Plugging in $A=C=2$, we have $\dfrac{\beta}{4}=\dfrac12$, so $\beta=2$. Now that we have $g$, we add $\dfrac52$ to obtain $f$.

As far as uniqueness, since there are four equations and five (homogeneous) variables, we should expect more solutions, indexed perhaps by one real parameter. We can certainly produce similar shapes with less symmetry, by considering first curves of the form $\dfrac{x}{A(x-h)^2+k}$. I'm not sure whether one of those, with non-zero $h$, could satisfy the needed conditions.

---

Edit: Indeed, dropping symmetry, we can find other solutions. Try $(9,-3,9,4,-2,4)$. This shows that the original problem cannot be solved uniquely without some additional assumption (although we do still have $A=C$, in this example).

Comment: Hi. In your last edit, $f(0)\ne2.5$

Comment: Also, while assuming $g(x)$, how can we be sure that the coefficients in denominator will be same as before i.e. A, C?

Comment: Also, I understood till $y=0$ being horizontal asymptote. After that, how $\frac aA=\frac52?$

Comment: @aarbee yes, this is very strange. Four years ago, when I posted this answer, it seems I answered a different question than the one we see here. I found a function satisfying the condition that $f\to\frac52$ as $x\to\infty$ instead of $f(0)=\frac52$. I'll have to make some edits. I'm surprised this went unnoticed at the time!

Comment: I think I understood a little bit more. At $x$ tending to infinity, $g(x)$ is becoming zero. So, $f(x)$ will be $2.5$. So, $a=2.5A$. I just wonder how the coefficients in $g(x)$ denominator are same as that of $f(x)$

Comment: I think I got $g(x)$. When we write $f(x)-2.5$, the denominator coefficients should remain same.

Comment: Also, as per the post, the points on the curve are $(1,2), (-1,3)$ instead of $(1,3),(-1,2)$.

Comment: Also, instead of plugging $A=2$ in $g(1)$, if we just write it in terms of $A$, we get $\beta=-A$. Plugging this back, we get a unique solution.

Comment: Your solution is very crafty. I learnt a lot from this. Thanks. +1.

Comment: I found another solution [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-function-given-byfx-leftdfracax2-2bx-cax2-2bx-cright-has/) but couldn't understand. They are saying for extrema, the denominator should be minimum. Can you help?